# LEFT JOIN of a string

Tags: sql, mysql, select, left-join

On part of my site, users enter multiple search terms.  Each of these search terms may return 0 rows, or return several.  I perform a UNION on all the searches and get the rows.

Thing are much easier for me if I can get all the search terms in the response, regardless of whether they return any rows.  Is there a way to essentially LEFT JOIN a string (in this case the search term) to a SELECT query?

**More information update:**

I have a table Books with the field Title.

The user enters up to 10 title search_terms, and I currently perform a UNION on all these to get matching rows.  So it's like

```
SELECT $s[0] AS Search_Term,* WHERE Title LIKE '%$s[0]%'  UNION 
SELECT $s[1] AS Search_Term,* WHERE Title LIKE '%$s[1]%' ...etc
```

I'd like it so that if there are no results for a given search, I still get the Search_Term back along with the NULL Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Full Text Search (FTS) this way, if you concatenate the array values together:

```
   SELECT x.searchterm,
          b.*
     FROM (SELECT $s[0 ... 20] AS search_term) x
LEFT JOIN BOOKS b ON MATCHES(b.title) AGAINST (x.searchterm)
```

`$s[0 ... 20]` is a placeholder for the search terms concatenated into a single string, separating each term with a space character.

The LEFT JOIN will ensure that you get your search term and NULL for the rest of the columns if nothing matches.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what he wants:

--Results--

```
Search Term____Title________________________________Author______Call No
cats           How to Care for Millions of Cats     JohnB       B.342
kittens        Why Kittens are your only Friends    Old Lady    L.4239
rabies         null                                 null        null

etc.
```

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE count
    count > 0
      'Search Term', books.title 'Title', books.author 'Author', books.call_no 'Call No'
    count <= 0
      'Search term 1'
  END CASE
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT('Search term 1') count, 'Search term 1' 'Search Term' ,*
   FROM books
   WHERE books.title LIKE 'Search term 1');
```

*(you'll have to work the kinks out though)*

Comment: I want the Search term in the results, even if facts.description != the search term

Comment: @babonk, no need to down-vote, I'm trying to help!  You hardly provided any details; your question was vague!!

Comment: @JohnB: I added more info on the query, etc.  Sorry for the question being vague

Comment: Thanks JohnB (that is indeed what I'm going for).  Would there be a way to shorten it like OMG Ponies's query?

Comment: I'm sorry babonk, OMG Ponies is way out of my league!  Use his query!  +1 OMG

Comment: ok, will do.. thanks for the answer though.. i only downvoted because in the past people have ignored my questions because there's an upvoted one there that doesn't answer it. (removed the downvote)

Answer (score 0):

Join conditions work just like WHERE conditions, you can use "LIKE" or "=" to join on the condition of your choice. If you need more detail, I'll need some query examples and table definitions.